# Stochastic transition matrix clarification

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

I am studying stochastic processes, and I don't quite understand what does it mean to go from state $i$ to state $j$ in two steps. As given in the definition and properties page on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix#Definition_and_properties) , if there is a stochastic matrix $P$ and $P_{i,j}$ is denoted the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to $j$ then transitioning in "two steps" is the $i,j$ th element of the square of $P$.

My questions are:

> 1)What does it mean to move from $i$ to $j$ in two steps? Can't we do this in one step? If there's a markov chain where you can move from $i$ to $j$ in only one way(one step) then how do you move onto the $j$ in two steps?
>
> 2)Why do we multiply the matrix in order to find the value? What's the intuition behind this? If you could provide maybe a simple example that would clarify this for me that would be great.

Comment: I'm sure you'll see, very intuitively, the answer to question (1) if you would replace "state" by "city" and "move" by "fly," as in "What does it mean to fly from New York to Los Angeles in two steps?  Can't we do this in one step?" Your travel agent, at least, will understand exactly what this means and can help you decide whether to fly nonstop or to stop on the way and, if so, where that stop will be made.

Comment: @whuber Oh thanks, I see now. So if it's 'cheaper' then we would go to LA in 2 steps, 1 otherwise. But then why do we multiply the whole matrices to get that value?

Comment: Consider all the people traveling from NY to LA, via any route. Those who have one layover may travel through Chicago, Denver, Salt Lake City, etc.  If you keep track of them all and tabulate the travelers according to which city they stop at, you will write down the formula for matrix multiplication.  If that's not obvious, then some time consulting an elementary account of matrix multiplication contained in any *non-mathematical* textbook will be helpful, because virtually all such accounts use examples like this to motivate the rules of matrix operations.